# How to create a portal which can realtime preview widgets and generate widget embeddable link using React

Tags: reactjs, widget, create-react-app, preview, react-widgets

I am trying to build a portal to create widgets. This portal will allow users to create different types widgets and preview how that widget look like in realtime.

Finally, this portal should be able to generate a unique link for a particular widget which has the capability of rendering the same widget configured by the user in anywhere when they pasted it (ex: like an online article).

For you reference I am attaching a design of my preview page.(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lP3h5YYExrPWOcAaRmf2YupZ6qjqrINH)

Please help me to find the best way to implement this by using React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use redux and store the widget preview config (widget name, layout, color, ...)

So your preview render will base on the stored widget conf 
Your side parts will update the stored config

All your update will rerender the widget preview with the new config

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I have to create a separate library project to do the widget rendering part. So the embeddable link always will be pointing to that script. When some one copy that link and paste that to somewhere basically it will create and iframe to render the widget. So the same way we can do the widget preview part as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have to create a separate library project to do the widget rendering part. So the embeddable link always will be pointing to that script. When some one copy that link and paste that to somewhere basically it will create and iframe to render the widget. So the same way we can do the widget preview part as well.

Any suggestions?